# Proving $a^{-2}bcd+b^{-2}cda+c^{-2}dab+d^{-2}abc\geqslant a+b+c+d$

Tags: inequality, symmetric-polynomials, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, muirhead-inequality

> If $a,b,c,d$ are positive real numbers, then prove that $$\frac{bcd}{a^2}+\frac{cda}{b^2}+\frac{dab}{c^2}+\frac{abc}{d^2}\geqslant a+b+c+d$$

**Attempt:**
$$\frac{bcd}{a^2}+\frac{cda}{b^2}+\frac{dab}{c^2}+\frac{abc}{d^2} = \frac{abcd}{a^3}+\frac{abcd}{b^3}+\frac{abcd}{c^3}+\frac{abcd}{d^3}$$

Using AM-GM inequality:
$$abcd\big[a^{-3}+b^{-3}+c^{-3}+d^{-3}\big]\geqslant4abcd(abcd)^{-\frac{1}{4}}$$

Could anyone help me?

Comment: Set $a=b=c=d=1$. Then you get $4>4$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We'll replace $a\rightarrow\frac{1}{a}$ and similar.

Thuse, we need to prove that
$$a^3+b^3+c^3+d^3\geq abc+abd+acd+bcd,$$
which is AM-GM or Muirhead.

For example
$$\sum_{cyc}a^3=\frac{1}{3}\sum_{cyc}(a^3+b^3+c^3)\geq\frac{1}{3}\sum_{cyc}3\sqrt[3]{a^3b^3c^3}=\sum_{cyc}abc$$
and we are done!